# How to address an element of variable vector for coupled system of ODE while using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am using Mathematica from around 10 months. I want to solve numerically a system of equations with number of equations more than 35 to 40. System of equations is shown below for small number of equations and with simplified form.

$$\begin{pmatrix}  x1''\\x2''\\x3''\\x4''\\x5'' \end{pmatrix}
+ M_{(5 \times  5)} \begin{pmatrix} x1\\x2\\x3\\x4\\x5 \end{pmatrix}
+ V1_{(5 \times 1)} xb''   +   V2_{(5 \times 1)} xb
= 0, \\ \\
  \text{and }    \;\;\; xb=G (x5- \alpha x5^3) \cos \Omega t$$

Here, `xb` is calculated from one of the vector elements `x5` itself. I have written the code (as shown below) where `xb` is a given function and it is not very difficult.

```
   V1={{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}};  f=5;
    s = NDSolve[{x''[t] + M.x[t] ==V1*f*Sin[t],x[0] == {1, 1, 1, 1}, x'[0] == {1, 1, 1, 1}}, x, {t, 0, 8}]
    Plot[x[t]/.First[s],{t,0,8}]
```

Here, `f=5` (constant) I have taken, but actually `f=f(x5)` and that actually makes the system of equation complete. If I use `f=x[[5,1]]` than I get error, 
`Part::partd: Part specification x[[5,1]] is longer than depth of object.`

Can someone tell me, how I can address the element of variable vector using `NDSolve` for introducing $xb=G (x5- \alpha x5^3) \cos \Omega t$.

Comment: You can use Indexed[x[t], 5] instead, but you will have to work around taking derivatives of such objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Numerical Method of Lines Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) demonstrates a relatively clean way of setting up your type of problem.

You did not define $\alpha$, $G$, $\Omega$, $M$ or $V2$, so I chose arbitrary and uninteresting values (coupled systems are very easy to make unstable).  Here is an example workflow:

```
n = 5;
f = 5;
G = 1;
alpha = 1;
omega = 1/10;
V1 = Flatten@{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}};
V2 = {1, -1, 3, -1, 1};
X[t_] = Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
Xb[t_] = G (Subscript[x, 5][t] - alpha 5^3 X[t]) Cos[omega*t];
M = -(ConstantArray[1, {n, n}] - 
     Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]);
eqns = Thread[
   D[X[t], t, t] + M.X[t] + f*V1.D[Xb[t], t, t] + V2.Xb[t] == 
    ConstantArray[0, n]];
initc = Thread[X[0] == Table[1, {n}]];
initcp = Thread[(D[X[t], t]) == Table[1, {n}]] /. t -> 0;
system = Join[eqns, initc, initcp];
s = NDSolve[system, X[t], {t, 0, 8}];
Plot[Evaluate[X[t] /. First@s], {t, 0, 8}]
```

[image: NDSolve Plot]

Comment: M, V1 are Matrix and vector 5*5 and 5*1 respectively. Arbitrary values can be taken to check problem. Actually their order is more than 20.

Comment: I added some uninteresting arbitrary values.  It was very easy to make the system go unstable with "random" arbitrary values.

Comment: Thanks.. It is working perfectly and it is stable also with properly given values.

Comment: But, when the method is applied with NDSolveValue (to get value at specific t), it gives error "No functions were specified for output from NDSolveValue" and without the Subscript usage, NDSolveValue works fine for a group of equations.  Any idea??